# Facebook FQL query with Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Testing tool for developers Graph Api Explorer, when I make the following FQL query:

select uid, about_me from user where uid = me ()

With access_token without User Data Permissions & Friends selected, I think you should get an error OAuth, needing permits or user_about_me friends_about_me about_me field to query the user table, but instead received the correct answer.

I have the same behavior from the Graph API bio selecting the field and even from an Android test app that I used to test.

What is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, when you first accessed and installed the [Developers Site](https://developers.facebook.com/) application, you were prompted with a permissions dialog. At that time you granted access to the basic information you are seeing.

Comment: You mean the fact of entering the application Graph API Explorer and I have permission? So I have need for tokens? About_me? Profile is basic information is information or Users and Friends Permissions? Sorry if I do not quite understand the answer.

We tested with another user of Facebook and the behavior is the same.

Comment: If you are testing with the api explorer, then it already has the correct permissions and access token it needs to get that basic data. There is a [drop down in the top right or the api explorer](http://i.imgur.com/O1HJ4.png) that you can use to set the appropriate access tokens for a specific application. If you set it to your application, then you won't be able to see that data unless the user has already installed your application.